# How to get Mac OS X to use a printer shared by a Windows XP machine

Tags: macos, windows-xp, networking, printer, printing

I've got a Windows XP machine sharing a printer for everyone on the network, but now I'm trying to get a Mac OS X machine to print to the printer shared by this Windows XP machine. Does anyone know of some documentation that explains how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3771

"Find in browser": Windows- Used to add your printer being shared via the Windows printer sharing protocol (CIFS).  Tip: See Mac 101: File Sharing for details about how to add your Mac to a Windows Workgroup.  This is often needed to see Windows printer shares.

The answer you want is around that section of documentation.